# How to calculate scale size of sprite object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, getpixel

I have image of sprite having size 90 X 120 and I want to load that image in unity,

Now when I am loading that image it is look like stretch in height and width I am setting scale value of the object but It is look like not proper as I am just doing error and trial method.

can any one tell me how to calculate so the I can load proper image of sprite in scene.
means if my **main camera size is 100** and **type is orthographic**.
and when I create sprite object below are setting which is been given to object

**Texture type = Sprite 

Sprite Mode = single 

Pixel To units = 100 

pivot = center 
 
Max size = 1024 

Format = 16 Bits**

Now can any one tell me if any setting need to change or **how to calculate the scale size of sprite as per above info so that sprite look good**

Comment: Don't know what you mean looking good? and if scale x and y are the same value, sprite should look just fine.

Comment: Means If we load image of above size in UIImageView Object in native IOS then we set size of the view is 90X120 and Image set in the view I want to do same thing in unity but unity don't allow size of sprite it allow us to set scale size, So that I want to know scale size of the object.

Comment: This should help you out: http://indiehoodgames.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/pixel-perfect-calculator-for-orthographic-camera-unity3d/

Comment: A screenshot or sample image would really help. Anything else seems correct, of course it is expected that the rect transfrom of the sprite and its parents is 1/1/1 or so.